# Error sending text to node with quotation marks ``

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, text

I'm working on a project with node, and I have to send it text from a textarea, and it turns out that in one of the cases, in the textarea the text contains these quotes:

```
`test message`
```

and when reading the body with:

```
const body = req.body;
```

I get the following error:

```
(node: 20568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I have tried to send the same text without those quotes, using the double quotes "or the single quotes' and it works fine for me, but I need it to work with these quotes` someone knows how I can solve this error ??? Thank you very much.

my current code is as follows:

```
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ copy",
                data: `text = $ {$ (this) .val ()} & id = $ {id}`,
                success: function () {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

and in the server in node I receive the data such that:

```
const body = req.body;
```

and when reading the body is when I get the error

Comment: What’s with the extra white-space all over the place here …? `url: "/ copy"`, `text = foo & id = 123` – sounds like asking for trouble somewhere down the line.

Comment: no problem, i copy the code so stackoverflow format it, in my code i have it whitout spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the ` in the string before you pass it to Node.js?

const str = String(req.body);
const body = str.replace("`", "'");

That's if you don't actually need to work with the ` character once it's passed through.

Comment: and if i need to work with it, how can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to send your data.

Also (and this may be your *actual* problem here): it looks a bit strange to send data as querystring in a POST request, so try sending `data` as `Object`. Furthermore: remove excess whitespace from the url and query(-string).

Anyway, I [don't think the backticks are the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/yhc04961/)

```js
const textValue = 
  encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector("input").value);

console.log(
  `Value encoded: ${textValue}`,
  `\nValue decoded: ${decodeURIComponent(textValue)}`,
  `\nSend data as Object: `,
  { 
    data: {
      text: textValue,
      id: "someId", }
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="`some text`">
```